# Gameobject not destroyed OnCollisionEnter

Tags: unity, c#

I have this GameObject with the tag coin I am trying to destroy when the player collides with it using this code located in a player script attached to the player

```c#
    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
        var hit = col.gameObject;
        if(hit.tag == "Coin"){
            Destroy(hit.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

However upon collision nothing is happening

Answer (score 2):

First you must check:

1. **collider** => IsTrigger =>false
2. **Rigidbody** => IsKinematic =>false
3. you mentioned 3d so check their gameObjects  **z position**
4. finally you check your **tag name** into corresponding to their gameobject

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue the problem was in order to use `OnCollisionEnter` at least one of the objects must have a `rigidbody` component attached

Answer (score 0):

Few things you have to keep in mind.

- Rigidbody must attached to either `Gameobject`
- Make sure that your script attached to the `GameObject` is **not** `isTrigger` checked.
- Verify if the `OnCollisionEnter` is being executed, by breakpoints or logs.
- Make sure the tag of other `GameObject` (col.gameObject)
- And you don't need to destroy `hit.gameObject` as `hit` is already a `GameObject`.

You can do it like

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){

    var hit = col.gameObject;

    Debug.Log("In collision enter");

    if(hit.tag == "Coin"){
        Debug.Log("In destroy check");
        Destroy(hit);
    }
}
```